# Ansible jinja2 template from json file

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have a json host_names.json file with the structure of

```
{
 "host1": "run on host 1",
 "host2": "run on host 2",
 "host3": "run on host 3"
}
```

In the same directory, I have a playbook run.yml

```
---
- name: Run this
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Template
     src: "template.j2"
     dest: "/my_dest/my_file.txt
```

I'd like the template to look like this:

```
#########
# host1 #
#########

run on host 1

end

#########
# host2 #
#########

run on host 2

end 

#########
# host3 #
#########

run on host 3

end
```

How would my template look for this? This is what I currently have

```
{% for a, b in host_names %}
###########
# {{ a }} #
###########

{{ b }}

end

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, was just

```
{% for a, b in host_names.iteritems %}

########## 
#  {{a}} # 
##########

{{ b }}

end 

{% endfor %}
```